# Calculate an aspect ratio that includes a fixed offset using CSS/SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive-design, core-web-vitals

I'm looking to set the aspect ratio of a div that is sized responsively, to be square plus an offset. I want the height to equal width plus the offset.

Something like:

```
.div {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / (1 + 30px); // This is the part I'm struggling with
}
```

In other words, if the width is 300px, the height should be 330px. If the width is 600px, the height should be 630px.

Is this possible with CSS/SCSS? Or am I approaching the issue the wrong way?

I've tried various combinations of calc() and var(), but all of them end up turning into invalid CSS rules.

Ex:

```
{
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / (calc(calc(var(width) + 30px) / var(width))
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest `aspect-ratio: 1/calc(1 + var(--offset))`, assuming a custom property such as `--offset: 30px` exists; but without a little more context as to what you're trying to do it's difficult to really say. Also, do those elements really have a class of "div"?

Answer (score 0):

That's not an aspect-ratio.

You cannot use `px` in the `aspect-ratio` property because it's supposed to be a ratio. So can't use fixed units like pixels or it would have a different aspect-ratio depending how wide it is, which means it is not an aspect ratio.

Without fully understanding what it is you are trying to achieve, it seems to me the best option would be to set the aspect-ratio on the fixed inner element, and have the offset as a separate element - both of which together make the total element.